# SQL Server 2005 - WHERE NOT EXISTS and a complicated script inside of the NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, not-exists, cross-apply

Script objective: get a list of numbers from a list where the numbers don't show up in another list.

The complications: the other list of numbers can only be obtained via a complicated script - and for some reason I'm getting no results when I KNOW there should be; since the first list will contain ALL the numbers and the second list of numbers will only contain some numbers; so I should be getting some results.

The script I have written (censored)

```
SELECT A.Number
FROM   sometable AS A
       INNER JOIN othertable AS B
               ON A.Data = B.Data
       INNER JOIN othertable2 AS C
               ON B.Data = C.Data
       INNER JOIN othertable3 AS D
               ON C.Data = D.Data
WHERE  D.Data = 'int'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT A.Number
                       FROM   sometable AS C
                              anothertable AS B
                                      ON C.Data = B.Data
                              INNER JOIN anothertable AS E
                                      ON B.Data = E.Data
                              INNER JOIN anothertable AS A
                                      ON E.Data = A.Data
                              CROSS apply (SELECT DG.Data
                                           FROM   atable AS DG
                                           WHERE  B.Data = DG.Data) D
                       WHERE  D.Data IN ( 'int', 'int', 'int', 'int' ))
```

If I run the part1 (before the non exist) it works fine

If I run part2 (the data within the non exist) it also works fine - with different, and less results (containing numbers from part1)

But together they don't. So I need to know how to do this if not exist is not what I need to use?

Comment: Your not exist is used with a subquery, your subquery uses the same table and aliases as your outer query.  This is going to keep it from being a corelated subquery and probably where your problem is coming from.  Also, having the same item in an IN list, does not do anything useful.

Comment: FYI: It useless to use `DISTINCT` inside an `EXIST` query. It does not matter **what** the query returns, just the number of rows: zero or more than zero.

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in Subquery `..sometable AS C anothertable AS B..` should be `..sometable AS C Inner Join anothertable AS B..` **Inner Join** is missing

Comment: I was using not exists in the wrong way which was the entire issue. I think I get it now. PM 77-1's response makes sense to me. @NoDisplayName - the tables were not the same in both queries; but the data would be comparable. I was trying to simplify from the real version. I did miss an inner join declaration inside of the not exists on the demo script; but not on the real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query is working as it should. Since there are **some rows exists** in your sub query the outer query didn't produce any result but that is not the right way to complete your objective

Your Objective

> Get a list of numbers from a list where the numbers don't show up in another list.

can be done in two ways.

Using `Not Exists`

```
SELECT A.Number
FROM   sometable AS A
       INNER JOIN othertable AS B
               ON A.Data = B.Data
       INNER JOIN othertable2 AS C
               ON B.Data = C.Data
       INNER JOIN othertable3 AS D
               ON C.Data = D.Data
WHERE  D.Data = 'int'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   sometable AS CC
                              INNER JOIN anothertable AS BB
                                      ON Cc.Data = BB.Data
                              INNER JOIN anothertable AS EE
                                      ON BB.Data = EE.Data
                              INNER JOIN anothertable AS AA
                                      ON EE.Data = AA.Data
                              CROSS apply (SELECT DG.Data
                                           FROM   atable AS DG
                                           WHERE  BB.Data = DG.Data) DD
                       WHERE  DD.Data IN ( 'int', 'int', 'int', 'int' )
                              AND aa.number = a.number)
```

Or by using `Not IN`

```
SELECT A.Number
FROM   sometable AS A
       INNER JOIN othertable AS B
               ON A.Data = B.Data
       INNER JOIN othertable2 AS C
               ON B.Data = C.Data
       INNER JOIN othertable3 AS D
               ON C.Data = D.Data
WHERE  D.Data = 'int'
       AND A.Number NOT IN (SELECT AA.number
                            FROM   sometable AS CC
                                   INNER JOIN anothertable AS BB
                                           ON Cc.Data = BB.Data
                                   INNER JOIN anothertable AS EE
                                           ON BB.Data = EE.Data
                                   INNER JOIN anothertable AS AA
                                           ON EE.Data = AA.Data
                                   CROSS apply (SELECT DG.Data
                                                FROM   atable AS DG
                                                WHERE  BB.Data = DG.Data) DD
                            WHERE  DD.Data IN ( 'int', 'int', 'int', 'int' )
                                   AND aa.number = a.number)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand why this would work and mine would not. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the subquery, run independently, produces results. Therefore, when run in the `NOT EXISTS` clause, it will always produce results and therefore the clause will always be false.

My guess is that what you meant is more along the lines of `WHERE A.Number NOT IN ( ... )`